# Multline spacing between lines of an equation too wide

Tags: multline

The `multline` environment seems to be behaving very oddly for me in that the spacing between different lines of an equation seems to be off. For example, for the following line of latex code,

```
\begin{multline*}
        p(x) = 3x^6 + 14x^5y + 590x^4y^2 + 19x^3y^3\\ 
        - 12x^2y^4 - 12xy^5 + 2y^6 - a^3b^3
\end{multline*}
```

I'm getting the following result
[image]

What I should be getting is

[image]

(which was taken from [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Aligning%20equations%20with%20amsmath#:%7E:text=For%20equations%20longer%20than%20a,and%20aligned%20to%20the%20right)).

I don't understand why I'm getting these results. Can someone please explain why? (Note that I've set the margin of my pages to 1 inches on all sides using the `geometry` package.)

**UPDATE (1/1/2021) :** Thanks to Mico, it seems that the issue is indeed caused by the custom setting of the page margins. I guess the question is now:  is there anyway to fix the output for the `multline` environment when the margins of the pages are custom set (such as when the margins are set to 1 inch on all sides)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Thanks! Glad to be here

Comment: Just out of curiosity: The sixth order polynomial equation easily fits on a single line. What are you trying to achieve by splitting it across two lines?

Comment: Good observation. The equation I'm using here is actually just for reference. The actual equation I'm using is longer.

Comment: The difference between the outputs of your code and the one in the Overlaef tutorial surely lies mainly in the value of the `margin` parameter: You set `margin=1in`, whereas the Overleaf tutorial uses something closer to `margin=2.5in`. Put differently, the `\textwidth` parameter in the overleaf example is 3" smaller than in your code.

Comment: You're right. I've just changed the code to `\RequirePackage[margin=2.5in]{geometry}` and I'm able to reproduce the result exactly the same as the one shown in the Overleaf tutorial.

Comment: In this case, I guess the question is there anyway to fix the output for the `multline` environment when the margins of the pages are custom set (such as when the margins are set to 1 inch on all sides)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `mathtools` and its `\multlined` definition, you can obtain:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[                  % <---
\begin{multlined}   % <---
        p(x) = 3x^6 + 14x^5y + 590x^4y^2 + 19x^3y^3\\
        - 12x^2y^4 - 12xy^5 + 2y^6 - a^3b^3
\end{multlined}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the width of the environment maybe set as the second optional argument of `multlined`.

Comment: Thanks @Zarko. This completely solves my problem. It's the first time I'm coming across the `multlined` environment. It seems the usage is identical to the `multline` environment except that must be used inside another math environment.

Comment: Noted with thanks @Bernard.